# Republish does not work (static resources)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, publish

When i run my webapp in eclipse i get an 404 error as soon as i call the dispatcher Servlet. First i thought there must be something wrong in the code but everthing seemed to be fine.

I looked up the org.eclipse.wst.server.core and the classes folder of the wtpwebapps was empty, so it's clear that Tomcat can't find the class file.

I exported the project as a war file and deployed it with the manager app of the tomcat gui. This time it worked without a problem. After that i tried it again in eclipse and here it worked, too. So i again looked up the classes folder in wtpwebapps and found the comiled servlets.

Update:

it happens that the content of my dynamic web project does not get published correctly.
The web module and the server are marked as "Synchronized", but only partial content is deployed to wtpwebapps. I have to remove the project from the server, then do a rightclick --> Build Project and add again the web module to fix the problem.

When i modify a jsp, i immediately see in the servers tab that tomcat republishes. If i do the same with servlet no change takes place in the tab.

So why does Tomcat not republishes the static resources ?

I am new to java/webapplications and eclipse, so please tell me what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try right clicking on the server and selecting "restart" after making changes in the servlet code. A jsp can be republished but not the servlet code, at least that's my case.
Whenever I do changes in servlet code I need to restart manually.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the option "Build automatically" in the Project tab was disabled. I don't know why because I'm sure I never changed it. But now it works.
I hope this will help others too.